# Getting Visual Studio Android Emulator for Lollipop & marshmallow

Tags: xamarin, visual-studio-2015, android-emulator

I've installed Visual studio 2015 & xamarin and I see that the visual studio emulator only has kitkat and nothing else.

Their website claims that lollipop is supported but I don't have the foggiest idea on how to get it.

EDIT: Should probably mention this, when I open up the visual studio emulator window I see the following error:

> Unable to establish a connection to Internet. Only device profiles for acquired platforms are shown

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed it, A spybot tool I installed to disabled some windows 10 stuff was blocking things needed for this tool, unblocked it and it works now.

Comment: This one: 
0.0.0.0 www.msftncsi.com

Answer (score 2):

> In Visual Studio 2015, you can install, uninstall, and start device profiles using the Emulator Manager. Access the Emulator Manager by choosing Tools, then Visual Studio Emulator for Android.

[image]

> By default, there are four pre-installed device profiles (KitKat and Lollipop phone/5" and tablet/7" configurations), as indicated by the white text and icons. Other profiles in the list will appear grayed out until you choose the Install Profile button and the installation completes. You can filter the list by API Level and click the details arrow on the bottom right-hand side of a profile to view its full configuration details.
>
> Once you've installed the set of profiles that you'd like to target, you can start these new profiles directly from the manager by pressing the green Play button. They will also appear in the debug target dropdown menu in any Visual Studio cross-platform mobile project type.

Ref: [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt228279.aspx)